# When we should use SIC2 and SIC3 in fixed effect?

Tags: international-economics, fixed-effects

SIC is the industry classification. The definition of SIC from [Bigelli, 2006](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/7d0d0c02-2fa3-3f02-bac0-f780f57a9ee7/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7B4a5dbf23-e4ee-33b6-a2d6-a7ee0bbe2f0b%7D) is

> Due to the low numbers of firms in some industries, we use the most
> detailed industry (SIC4) only if the number of companies in the
> industry was greater or equal to 3, otherwise we use the less detailed
> industry (SIC3) or the least detailed (SIC2).

In my sample, I want to use **industry*year fixed effect**. What I should do to justify that SIC2 or SIC3 is more suitable in my fixed effect ( I am working on an international study and my sample lasting 20 years)? Because in SIC2, is it too general? And in SIC3, maybe we face too many missing variables? I saw a couple of studies using SIC3 fixed effect but SIC2 (e.g. [Dasgupta, 2019](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/32/7/2587/5079300?redirectedFrom=fulltext))

From table IA5 of [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1111%2F1756-2171.12299&file=rand12299-sup-0001-InternetAppendix.pdf), they did the same thing with me and the least number of observation for their SIC3 is 36 ( but they did not say that clearly in their manuscript)